# GraphQL versioning, not nullable to nullable

Tags: graphql

At the begining we have schema

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  birthday: String!
}
```

After some time it was decided that birthday is not mandatory for new users, so the schema should change to

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  birthday: String
}
```

This is breaking change.

How to versioning case like this in GraphQL?

Comment: How about adding a field `version` into type `User` ?

Comment: @Romper good articles about graphql versioning are [here](http://graphql.org/learn/best-practices/#versioning) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/175). But in your specific case, I'm not sure why its a breaking change to just change the schema to `birthday: String` - old API requests/old data should still work.

Comment: @yishaiz old clients can crash, they know that this field is not nullable, but we will send null, because we don't have birthday of all users

Comment: I see. So in the links I gave you there are several approaches to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in [these official best practices](https://graphql.org/learn/best-practices/) under the section *versioning*, it isn't recommanded to do traditional API versioning in GraphQL even though there isn't any technical problems in doing so. I would feel that we are corrupting our model since it would introduce a technical field in a business API... which is definitely not ideal.

To help manage the API's evolution, they introduced the concept of *field deprecation* as described in [this link](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec--deprecated).

To summarize in a few words, I would say that you have basically two solutions:

1. Do versioning anyway;
2. Set your field *birthday* as deprecated and add a new one with an equivalent name (*birthday_date* maybe?). Obviously, don't forget to tell your api clients to use this new field. In the long run, remove the deprecated field.